# Connection dropped but endPoints did not change or remained same

Tags: jsplumb

How will I come to know easily that an attempt was made by dragging one connection, left in between having no change in endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get notified when a endpoint is dragged to make connection but dropped such that no connection was made. To attain this we need to handle 2 events:

1.event triggered when connection was made. (jsPlumbConnection)

2.event triggered when endpoint stopped dragging. (dragOptions: {stop})

***NOTE:***  **jsPlumbConnection** event is triggered before **stop** event.

Maintain a global variable(FLAG) which is initially false and set to true when connection is made. While endpoint is stopped dragging we check FLAG for our result.

```
FLAG=false; //global variable

jsPlumb.bind("jsPlumbConnection", function(ci) {  //Register event when connection is made
            flag=true;  // set to true when connection is made
});

var e = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("DOM_ELEMENT", {
                                endpoint:"Dot",
                                hoverPaintStyle:{ fillStyle:"red" },
                                anchor:"Right",
                                dragOptions: {
                                stop:function() {  //Register event when endpoint stopped dragging
                                         if(FLAG===false) 
                                                      alert("No connection was made");
                                                 else
                                                      FLAG=false; // Reset variable for next use
                                }
                              } 
                           });
```